# $P_3$-factors for 3-regular, 3-connected cubic graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, factorization

Suppose that $G=(V,E)$ is a simple graph.

We know if $G$ is 3-regular, 3-connected and $|V|=4k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$, then $G$ has a $P_4$-factor.

**Question.** Let $G=(V,E)$ be 3-regular, 3-connected graph and $|V|=3k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Does $G$ have a $P_3$-factor?

Comment: What is a $P_k$-factor?

Comment: Sleuthing shows that $P_k$ is a path on $k$ vertices, so the OP's question is whether the vertices of $G$ can be decomposed into triples, where each triples forms the vertex set of a path on three vertices, and these paths are disjoint.

Comment: @Igor - the $P_3$ was not my problem, it was the factor part that I could not immediately find. In particular, do the triples need to induce $P_3$ or are they permitted to induce $K_3$ as well? (The book you linked seems to suggest that either is allowed.)

Answer (score 2):

As of 2011 this was open, see Akiyama and Kano's book: https://books.google.com/books?id=C9TkNBAhyC4C&pg=PA284&lpg=PA284&dq=P3+factor+3-connected+graph&source=bl&ots=oZIglvroNn&sig=D4oMqCBe_Hi7-af9QSjYVZwwc40&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OxCUVbyPIoeUyASJy5S4Dw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=P3%20factor%203-connected%20graph&f=false